# Как заставить D-LINK DWL-2100AP раздавать интернет, полученный через WiFi, в порт LAN?

Tags: wifi, маршрутизация

Приветствую всех участников форума!Вставить картинку никак не могу, поэтому для пояснения сути моей проблемы привожу эту ссылку:![[https://cacoo.com/diagrams/VTtgDtpBj4ZjUr9K][1]Коротко](https://cacoo.com/diagrams/VTtgDtpBj4ZjUr9K][1]%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE): проблема в том, что  1. Я не могу убрать / заменить и т.п. точку доступа DWL-2100AP. Всё, что могу - перезагрузить, сделать резет. Доступ по LAN. Не могу соединить в режиме WDS DWL-2100AP и DAP-1360. 2. D-LINK DWL2100-AP не хочет отдавать в LAN порт интернет, полученный по WiFi, если она настроена в режиме точки доступа и DAP-1360 подключен к ней в качестве клиента. 3. D-LINK DWL2100-AP случайным образом отдаёт полученный по WiFi интернет только на один компьютер в сети через LAN порт, если настроен как клиент и подключается к DAP-1360, как к точке доступа.Вопрос:Как (и можно ли вообще), в пп. 2 или 3 настроить сеть, чтобы интернет был на всех компьютерах в сети?UPD 20130302-0821 мск:Поменял картинку на диаграмму.upd 20130303-0737 мск:Исправил текст заголовка.>   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rbRL.jpg

Comment: а зачем тут 192.168.1.131 вообще? ip-адреса по DHCP получатся и через wifi, а ещё оно может давать "левый" gw, что создаст как раз такую проблему."не хочет отдавать в LAN порт интернет" ввело меня в ступор )) что это по-русски.

Comment: @ArcherGodson, поддерживаю)

Answer (score 1):

Как все мелко-то... Надписи совсем не читаемы. В [Cacoo][1] рисовать попробуйте:)По теме... 1. что [pathping][2] 8.8.8.8 говорит? 2. что [tracert][3] 8.8.8.8 говорит? 3. компы с двух сторон от вайфая между собой пингуются? 4. компы с двух сторон от вайфая в одной подсети (на всякий случай спрашиваю, а то бывало, знаете ли...) 5. вайфай стабильный? без помех/наводок/...?Общее ощущение - что- то у вас не так с маршрутизацией на узле 192.168.1.130, если до него, говорите, пинг доходит...UPОдним словом - подробную карту сети с таблицами маршрутизации в студию.UP_UP"Как вставить код"Помощь:1. ![alt text][4]2. ![alt text][5]Ну или просто выделив вставленный код кликнуть кнопочку "**{}**"![alt text][6]А без форматирования это будет **просто текст** - plain text...  [1]: https://cacoo.com/  [2]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathping  [3]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracert  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYrA1.jpg  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL0zy.jpg  [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsw8t.jpg

Comment: @Zerglyn, @areshin, не пробовали открыть изображение по прямой ссылке, получив тем самым ее полный размер?

Comment: @areshin, там даже моста не нужно, мне кажется. Так как все соединено LAN'ами. Насчет роутера вы правы, но тогда не понятно, почему не работает второй компьютер слева, у которого верный шлюз. Т.е. что-то здесь не сходится и я полагаю, что где-то в пункте 4, приведенном выше.

Comment: ping  на внешний ip правого WNDR проходит? на DNS провайдера? на шлюз провайдера?> 2 --- 100/ 100 =100% 0/ 100 = 0% noinet [0.0.0.0]А почему вообще 192.168.1.131 - шлюз??? Его ролью вижу а)"свитч" и, максимум, б)"DHCP". А шлюз, какбэ, 192.168.1.130, не?

Comment: @Dex, считаю, что, ожидая помощи, можно постараться предоставить наиболее полную информацию о проблеме в удобочитаемом виде. ИМХО...

Comment: @r72cccp, то есть "как вставить"? Ctrl+c -> Ctrl+v... Отформатировать, как код - четыре пробела, кажется...    здесь кодUPДля создания блоков кода или другого форматированного текста, отступите четыре пробела:    Данная строка будет отображаться в моноширинном шрифте. Вы не увидите    первые 4 пробела, но все остальные будут сохранены.        Markdown и HTML отключены в блоках.    Это <i> не курсив </i>. И это не ссылка [ссылка](url)Для создания встроенного кода (не блока) используйте обратные кавычки:Нажмите на `<tab>`, а затем наберите`$`..............

Comment: .............Если необходимо отформатировать блок в списке, сделайте отступ в 8 пробелов:1. Первый пункт с полезной информацией.2. Второй пункт с включенным блоком кода:     Пропустите строку, сделайте отсуп в 8 пробелов.    Первые четыре пробела для списка.    Следующие - для определения блока кода.

Comment: А как? Я понял, что надо типа текст как-то обозначить, а чем? справку один раз случайно увидел по редактору, теперь ищу - толку нет.Как код выводить сюда без форматирования?

Answer (score 0):

1. Уберите ВСЕ роутеры и ВСЮ WiFi аппаратуру нафиг!
2. Поставьте один WiFi роутер (можно из тех, что были) на распределение сети из и-нета.
3. Для дистанции ~300м, если сигнала не хватает, то можно поставить дополнительную точку доступа в режиме повторителя (я так делал).
4. Второй WiFi маршрутизатор включите в режиме "моста", т.е. чтобы работал как WiFi свитч.

Comment: DWL-2100AP и DAP-1360 не могут связаться в режиме моста. Процессоры разные. DWL-2100AP стоит на крыше и сейчас туда доступа нет.  WNDR не берёт, у него вообще нет возможности внешние антенны цеплять, а без внешних WiFi работает.

Comment: И-нет по вашей схеме с DAP-1360 раздаётся? Ну и сделайте DAP-1360 мостом, это он умеет: http://www.dlink.ru/ru/products/2/1293_b.html Посмотрите внимательно там на "Режимы доступа". Вот я об этом!

Comment: А если ваши компы с обеих сторон (как на схеме), то проще между ними туннель протянуть! Только не спрашивайте сейчас как!

Comment: Есть вариант и с двойной маршоутизацией, но всё равно тогда туннель надо будет делать. А надо бы вспомнить мне! Была же у меня где-то похожая ситуация... В общем, ещё подумаю.

Answer (score 0):

А как вставить сюда вывод командной строки?

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Администратор>pathping 8.8.8.8  0  noinet [192.168.1.192]    1  192.168.1.131    2  * * *  Подсчет статистики за: 50 сек. ...  Исходный узел     Маршрутный узел  Прыжок  RTT   Утер./Отпр.   %   Утер./Отпр.  %   Адрес    0                                           noinet [192.168.1.192]                                  0/ 100 =  0%   |    1    0мс     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  192.168.1.131                                100/ 100 =100%   |    2  ---     100/ 100 =100%     0/ 100 =  0%  noinet [0.0.0.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

> D-LINK DWL2100-AP случайным образом отдаёт полученный по WiFi интернет только на один компьютер в сети через LAN порт, если настроен как клиент и подключается к DAP-1360

ftp://ftp.dlink.ru/pub/Wireless/DWL-2100AP/Firmware/Old/DWL2100AP-firmware-v210eu-r0302.tfpдолжно помочь, на более новых прошивках можно telnet-ом отключить эту опцию, но я не помню команды (давно это было). Перепрошиваете, ставите в режим клиента и радуетесь.